# How can I control the sharpness of corners using Subsurf?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying to make these corners sharper after SubSurf.

[image]
[image: What's the front of the obj]

The solution that comes to my mind is adding edge loops to limit its space, but when I try to add edge loops they also affect the intake shape in front of the object in the same loop, deforming it in the way I don't want (I want sharper edges, but not round as I've done)

[image]

Any ideas besides boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crease edges with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> as well as inputing the Crease value in the n panel:

[image]

[image]

It is also possible to model the edge loops in such a way so they get narrower where you need sharper corners or edges.

Using Subsurf is also not the only way to model things. It adds a lot of unnecessary geometry and it is always worth to consider if you could achieve similar forms with other modelling tools, for example, using bevels.

Comment: hadn't approach bevel modifier and creases 4 months ago and then i learnt it some weeks ago. thanks for the advice!